# C Declaration: Unique Construct

Tags: c++, c, kernel, declaration, definition

Linux kernel has the following definition inside **sched_class** struct definition.

```
#ifdef CONFIG_SMP
  int  (*select_task_rq)(struct task_struct *p, int task_cpu, int sd_flag, int flags);
  .......
  .......
```

Now what does this line mean, I have fairly good knowledge in C & C++. But I was having hard time understanding this declaration construct:

```
 int  (*select_task_rq)(struct task_struct *p, int task_cpu, int sd_flag, int flags);
```

Can someone please explain what does this mean and what it does.

Thanks

Comment: It's just a [function pointer](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a function pointer.

```
int (*select_task_rq)(struct task_struct *p, int task_cpu, int sd_flag, int flags);
```

means that `select_task_rq` is a pointer to a function returning an `int` and taking all those parameter types.

It can be set to any compatible function and called as if it were a fixed function name. It's sometimes used to provide a primitive form of polymorphism in C, or to allow easy switching between functions based on other information.

Comment: Awesome, did some wonderful research on it myself as well. But what if I want a generic pointer that points to any function like ANYRETURN function(ANYTYPE, ANYTYPE); ? I mean it should be more like a void pointer assignable to any type?

Comment: @Anup, you hit the nail on the head. A void pointer can be converted to/from any other pointer, including a function pointer.

Comment: @AnupSaumithri: In C++, you'd use `std::function<>` for that. It can point to any function, but still is typesafe and therefore can be called directly without cast (provided that you pass the right arguments, i.e. two `ANYTYPE` objects in this case)